# MongoDB BatchSize FindOptions isn't working how we expected in C# netcore backend

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

we are currently working with a collection of 4 million documents which we must process in our backend (netcore C #).

We are using cursors for batch processing. We believe we have made the correct configuration of the BatchSize but at the time of execution, the size of records we have of the cursor is very small compared to the BatchSize.

We would like to know if the way we are doing it is wrong or if we need to adjust something in the configuration. We are using mongo atlas.

We build a method called "GetInstallationsAsync" which returns the cursor that we will use.

[image]

In the screenshots that we show below you can see that the BatchSize is 50000 but the current cursor size count is 1609.

[image]

Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Find out what batch size is sent with your query.

Comment: https://p-mongo.github.io/mongodb-faq/batch-size/